# MS Access 2010 - Error with filtering via Timestamp

Tags: ms-access, vba, ms-access-2010

With the following code I get errors, when I try to set a filter on a subform after saving. Here is the code.

Try 1:

```
Dim rsNow As Date

rsNow = DLookup("Auftrag_Datum", "tblKundenliste", "[Auftrag_Datum] <= Now()")
'Debug.Print rsNow
Forms![MAIN_Planung]![frmPlanungDatenblatt].Form.Filter = "[Auftrag_Datum] = " & rsNow
Forms![MAIN_Planung]![frmPlanungDatenblatt].Form.FilterOn = True
```

Here comes error 3075. But why? Then I try:

```
Dim rsNow As Date

rsNow = DLookup("Auftrag_Datum", "tblKundenliste", "[Auftrag_Datum] <= Now()")
'Debug.Print rsNow
Forms![MAIN_Planung]![frmPlanungDatenblatt].Form.Filter = "[Auftrag_Datum] = '" & rsNow & "'"
Forms![MAIN_Planung]![frmPlanungDatenblatt].Form.FilterOn = True
```

But then the error is 3464!? Also I have tried to `Dim As String`, but still the same error.

Please help me.

Best greetz and THX.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Apply a proper format for the *string representation* of rsNow:

```
Forms![MAIN_Planung]![frmPlanungDatenblatt].Form.Filter = "[Auftrag_Datum] = #" & Format(rsNow, "yyyy\/mm\/dd hh\:nn\:ss") & "#"
```